# Error while using a function in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a function fadeIn defining some basic properties of animation view. I am trying to pass these values into my AnimatedView but getting an error:

The function I wrote for fadeIn is :

```
import {Animated} from 'react-native';

const fadeIn = ({delay = 0, duration = 500}) => {
    const initialStyle = new Animated.Value(0);
    const animation = Animated.timing(
        initialStyle,
        {
            toValue: 1,
            delay: delay,
            duration: duration,
            useNativeDriver: false,
        });
    return {initialStyle, animation};
};
```

but when I called this into my Login Component as:

```
console.log(fadeIn());
```

It threw an error: 
[image]

Comment: `console.log(fadeIn());`...you are not passing parameter, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are trying to destruct an object which is `undefined`.

Your `fadeIn` function takes an object as argument. But when you are calling the function you do not provide any value as parameter, which will yield `undefined`. So basically what is happening is the following:

```
const {delay = 0, duration = 500} = undefined // Throws error.
```

The simplest way to solve this would be to just provide a value when calling the `fadeIn` function like so:

```
fadeIn({delay: 0, duration: 1337})
```

But a more robust way of solving it is to use a default value for your function parameter (`const fadeIn = ({delay = 0, duration = 500} = {}) => { ... }`). If the function gets called with no parameter, or undefined, it will default to the provided default value, in this case `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

possible to handle this is to construct function with define parameters.

```
const fadeIn = (delay = 0, duration = 500) => { ... }
```

than you can call it as fallow

```
fadeIn()
```

or overwrite the parametr as

```
fadeIn(50, 1000)
```